# Importing .csv file from neo4j into Python?

Tags: python, csv, neo4j

I have a .csv file, that has been extracted from a neo4j database. How might i read this into Python? I tried using both pandas.read_csv and the built in csv module from python. However, the dataframe is extremely ugly, and it does not print all the values as is i opened the document in an online .csv viewer. The data set is something like 100k rows and 322 columns.

A few columns, and corresponding rows.

```
_index     _type           _id                                      \\    

cluedin    elasticentity  01fa6697-98c8-5522-89ae-12c0abf65174

cluedin    elasticentity  b7db9e8b-c328-57cd-8d5c-2a1996d966fd          
cluedin    elasticentity  9ae1c159-f4a9-5091-ae3f-491ea6127b56       
cluedin    elasticentity  2af8f8c7-afc9-5d61-9ef8-6751079f3cf5        

_source.entityType
/Document/Presentation
/Image
```

/Temporal/Date
   /Topic

Comment: can you show some lines of this csv ?

Comment: Yes. Can i possibly upload the file?

Comment: A couple of lines for the question should be enough

Comment: How would you do that considering the size? I did an attempt for you, as i edited the question.

Comment: So the lines like this `_source.entityType
/Document/Presentation
/Image` are part of the csv right ?

Comment: Which makes it an invalid csv, looks like more kaggle data set or sth like this

Comment: Yes those are lines from the csv. Though. Those are three rows from one column

Comment: It's supposed to have been exported as a csv. What can i do then? im supposed to do nlp with this data for someone, however that seems near impossible